# Can't join Server 2003 domain with XP Pro

Tags: windows-xp, vmware, windows-server-2003

I installed windows server 2003 on my laptop using vmware and also installed xp pro using vmware on my desktop pc .. I have setup a domain using the Server 2003 wizard but when I try to set up the XP machine to join the domain (called ABCD.edu), I get "A domain controller for the domain ABCD could not be contacted." how i can fix this problem?

Comment: are you on the same network? can you ping each other? check your network settings.

Comment: Request time out

Comment: check your network settings.... make sure they are connected and on the same subnet. Then make sure they are using the same DNS server or did you install the feature in your Windows Server 2003? You usually install AD/DNS/DHCP all on the same server if you are testing in your env...

Comment: btw, you should not use ".edu" locally unless you own it. Use ".local" or ".anything" besides edu, com, net etc....

Comment: I checked them ..still same error :(

Comment: The Problem in Vmware .. I checked on Bridge and still same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After 10 hours of searching and testing I solved this Problem.

This Problem can Happens for 2 reasons :

1- Bridge Problem.. before installing Windows Server you should check the Network adapter in vmware and I prefer check customize then choose "vm0" if your connection is wired then in advanced setting choose the NIC that the "vm0" will take.

2- Firewall problem... Not only windows firewall but even the firewall of anti virus you have.. in my situation I have Bitdefender internet Security 2015 and when i Disabled its firewall, The problem solved directly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to

1. install the DNS-server on the Windows 2003 machine and make it as AD-integrated DNS
2. Configure your XP machine to use the IP of Windows 2003 machine as DNS server